# Exec To Another Program + Child Death

Tags: c, linux, unix, fork

I'm trying to write a program where, based on a user input value 'n', I'm going to fork that many processes to run *simultaneously*. In addition, each child is trying to exec to another file that I've created, that will generate a x sleep time, and a x exit value. Ultimately, when a child dies, the parent needs to print the pid and exit_status. The important part is making sure that children death is x, and not concurrent. So far, there's two things I can't figure out.

1. Getting my execl to run my sleep.c file (as provided below).
2. Getting the children to fork and die randomly, not in an orderly fashion, and as a result printing who died, with their generated random exit status.

I have two files, Sleep.c and Ranchild.c.

SLEEP.C

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <time.h>

/* Generated random sleep time, and return random exit value */

int main()
{
    /* Calculate A Random Time To Sleep 1 - 10 Seconds*/
    srand(time(NULL));
    int r = (rand() % 10) + 1;

    printf("Sleep Time: %d\n", r);
    sleep(r);

    /* Calculate A Random Exit Value */
    int r2 = (rand() % 30) + 1;
    exit(r2);       
}
```

RANCHILD.C

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    /* Get User Input */
    int i, n;

    printf("Please Enter An Integer!\n");

    /* Test User Input */
    if(!scanf("%d", &n)) {
        printf("Invalid Input!\n");
        return -1;
    }   

    /* Initialize Needed Variables */
    pid_t pid[n];
    int status, exit_status;

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        if((pid[i] = fork()) < 0) {
            perror("Fork Failed!");
            return -2;
        }

        if(pid[i] == 0) {
            execl("sleep", "sleep", (char *)0);
} else {
    /* Print Child Results */
    if (waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG) == 0) {
        if(WIFEXITED(status)) {
            exit_status = WEXITSTATUS(status);
            printf("Exit Status From %d was %d!\n", pid[i], exit_status);
        }
    }   

}       
    }

    exit(0);
}
```

It never manages to exec to the Sleep file, and a sample of the result is this:

```
3
Exit Status From 27369 was 0!
Exit Status From 27370 was 0!
Exit Status From 27371 was 0!
Sleep Time: 4
Sleep Time: 4
Sleep Time: 4
```

Your help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: You can't check the value of `status` until you call `wait`.  I don't see a call to `wait`.

Comment: I added the wait, the result is still 0 =[ Maybe I added it wrong? Regardless of the status, the children are still dying concurrently.

Comment: They are dying concurrently because you are probably waiting for them in the "else" where you check on the status.  You are going to block on the `wait` and thus create one child at a time in your loop.

Comment: In the `sleep.c` code, since the child processes are all likely to be started at the same time (same second), using `time()` to seed `srand()` is unlikely to work well.  Use `getpid()` too; that is guaranteed to be unique.  You might also play with the sub-second part of the result of one of the sub-second timing functions (`clock_gettime()` or `gettimeofday()`, for example).  But on a multi-CPU chip, the PID is still unique and the time is not necessarily unique.  You have the same problem with the exit statuses, of course; all the children are likely to exit with the same status.

Comment: You'll need a loop around the `waitpid()` call rather than just an `if`.  And the whole waiting business should be done after you've created all the children, not as you create each one.

Comment: One other possibility would be to have the parent code initialize the random number generator, and then call `rand()` for each child, and have the child pass the random seed to the executed child process (as an argument formatted as a string); the child (your `sleep` program) would then use that argument to initialize its random number generator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `sleep.c`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>

/* Generated random sleep time, and return random exit value */
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int seed = time(0);
    if (argc > 1)
        seed = atoi(argv[1]);
    srand(seed);

    int r = (rand() % 10) + 1;
    int r2 = (rand() % 30) + 1;

    printf("%d: Seed: %d; Sleep: %d; Exit %d\n", (int)getpid(), seed, r, r2);

    sleep(r);
    exit(r2);       
}
```

#### `ranchild.c`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int n = 10;
    if (argc > 1)
        n = atoi(argv[1]);
    if (n <= 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: invalid number of processes %d\n", argv[0], n);
        return(1);
    }

    int i;
    pid_t pid[n];
    int t = time(0);
    srand(t);

    printf("Time/seed: %d\n", t);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int seed = rand();
        fflush(0);
        if ((pid[i] = fork()) < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: Fork Failed!\n", argv[0]);
            return -2;
        }
        if (pid[i] == 0)
        {
            const char command[] = "sleep";
            char argument[15];
            snprintf(argument, sizeof(argument), "%d", seed);
            execl(command, command, argument, (char *)0);
            fprintf(stderr, "%d: failed to execute %s\n", (int)getpid(), command);
            return(1);
        }
        printf("Child: %d (%d)\n", pid[i], seed);
    }

    int corpse, status;
    while ((corpse = waitpid(-1, &status, 0)) > 0)
    {
        if (WIFEXITED(status))
            printf("%d: Exit Status From %d was %d!\n",
                   (int)time(0), corpse, WEXITSTATUS(status));
        else
            printf("%d: Exit status from %d was 0x%.4X\n",
                   (int)time(0), corpse, status);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

#### Sample output

```
Time/seed: 1381199552
Child: 66443 (1670130041)
Child: 66444 (116849150)
Child: 66445 (1083610692)
Child: 66446 (1583573884)
Child: 66447 (1361431117)
Child: 66448 (134524634)
Child: 66449 (1802726994)
Child: 66450 (1733296282)
Child: 66451 (894940019)
66443: Seed: 1670130041; Sleep: 1; Exit 13
66452: Seed: 281435745; Sleep: 2; Exit 11
66444: Seed: 116849150; Sleep: 3; Exit 5
66449: Seed: 1802726994; Sleep: 3; Exit 30
66447: Seed: 1361431117; Sleep: 5; Exit 25
66445: Seed: 1083610692; Sleep: 5; Exit 8
66448: Seed: 134524634; Sleep: 5; Exit 23
66451: Seed: 894940019; Sleep: 6; Exit 22
66446: Seed: 1583573884; Sleep: 8; Exit 15
66450: Seed: 1733296282; Sleep: 10; Exit 16
Child: 66452 (281435745)
1381199553: Exit Status From 66443 was 13!
1381199554: Exit Status From 66452 was 11!
1381199555: Exit Status From 66444 was 5!
1381199555: Exit Status From 66449 was 30!
1381199557: Exit Status From 66447 was 25!
1381199557: Exit Status From 66445 was 8!
1381199557: Exit Status From 66448 was 23!
1381199558: Exit Status From 66451 was 22!
1381199560: Exit Status From 66446 was 15!
1381199562: Exit Status From 66450 was 16!
```

Comment: I made a silly error earlier but `srand(getpid());` does seem to work too which would avoid a lot of the above.

Comment: And so it (`srand(getpid())`) should work! It would avoid some of the above, but not as much as all that: in fact, it saves 8 lines out of 80, give or take the odd blank line, or about 10%.  Some of the extra code in my solution is showing that time elapsed between children dying.  You should be able to track what the children say about when and how they're going to die with what the parent sees.

Answer (score 2):

Suggest something like this. Jonathan is correct.  You need something better to seed `rand`.  The children will run so fast it is highly likely they will all end up with the same sleep times and exit codes.

```
int ret;

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{

    if ((pid[i] = fork()) < 0)
    {
        perror("Fork Failed!");
        return -2;
    }

    if (pid[i] == 0)
    {
        if ((ret = execl("sleep", "sleep", (char *)0)) == -1)
        {
            perror("execl");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
   if (wait(&status) == -1)
   {
      perror("wait"); exit(1);
   }

   if (WIFEXITED(status))
   {
       exit_status = WEXITSTATUS(status);
       printf("Exit Status From %d was %d!\n", pid[i], exit_status);
   }
}
```

child/execl program

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

/* Generated random sleep time, and return random exit value */

void getRandomNumbers(int *r1, int *r2)
{
    int fd;

    if (((fd = open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY))) == -1)
    { perror("open"); exit(1);}

    read(fd, r1, sizeof(int));
    read(fd, r2, sizeof(int));
    close(fd);

    return;
}

int main()
{
    int r1 = 0, r2 = 0;

    getRandomNumbers(&r1, &r2);

    int sleeptime = abs((r1 % 10)) + 1;

    printf("Sleep Time: %d\n", sleeptime);
    sleep(sleeptime);

    int exitcode = abs((r2 % 30)) + 1;

    exit(exitcode);
}
```

Comment: This covers the main program and the waiting loop quite nicely.  You've not (yet) addressed the (lack of) randomness in the behaviour of the children -- oh, OK, you have just covered it briefly.

Comment: Actually I came up with same as you - use `getpid()`.  I didn't figure that needed to be shown.

Comment: THANKS. It works! I used getpid() in the srand. Beauty, thank you!

Comment: Wait, I just realized, they're still dying concurrently. Is there any way to randomize their death? Or is it just not possible?

Comment: Yeah, I thought you might be jumping the gun.  I am struggling to get this to randomize too.  I am trying to think of something that isn't too convoluted.

Comment: Ugh, I think that's a little too complex for the program =/ I really appreciate all your help. I'll try to figure it out. You've pretty much helped me with most of it, so thank you!

Comment: It's not complex but I'm not sure how portable it is outside of linux.  The above seems to work ok but I didn't test it beyond 3 or 4 runs.